# Can I change settings as a Device Owner? (Android 4 Work)

Tags: android, android-settings

There are several settings (Bluetooth, uninstall block, etc) that can be changed if the application is registered as device owner. However, like in normal applications, it's not possbile to change the global settings (Airplane Mode, Developer Mode, etc).

Settings that can be changed:

- [Secure settings](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#setSecureSetting(android.content.ComponentName,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))
- [User restrictions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#addUserRestriction(android.content.ComponentName,%20java.lang.String))

**Is there a way to change [global settings](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global.html) as a device owner? Or can I set the settings during the set up of the device?**